# Django querying top weekly hits in a Database

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am currently using django's ORM functions to build a viable backend to my web application. I have an Model object in my models.py that relates to and is displayed in a specific url which keeps track of hits using https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount. I want to organize my web application better by displaying charts like (top "models" today, top "models" this week, top "models" this month, top "models" this year, top "models" all time)
Currently I have my code set up like so to attempt to get the top "models" this week as I don't see any better way to do this in the 'django-hitcount' documentation

```
modelList = MyModel.objects.all()



for model in modelList
    model.hit_count.hits_in_last(days=7)
 '''
 then somehow compare this models weekly hits 
 to all the other models weekly hits organized by the top 100
 i'd like to add the top 100 weekly models to a new list then render it '''
```

The code comments are essentially my question. I'm not at all fluent in python or Django, Java is my primary language, so forgive me if this question sounds foolish

Comment: Its going to be hard to answer without knowledge of the hitcount module but you'd want to annotate based on the latest hits then orderby that. i.e `annotate(latest_hits=Q('latest_hits_querything')).orderby('latest_hits')[:100]`

Comment: Since the question is kinda specific to this package, you might have better luck asking for this at the GitHub project issue tracker. Looks like django-hitcount is under active development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used this package, but after checking the [models definition](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/master/hitcount/models.py), they use `GFK` to store hitcounts for any or your models, so in order to filter/annotate on their models you can define your own [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ..

    hitcounts = GenericRelation(
        HitCount,
        content_type_field='content_type',
        object_id_field='object_pk',
    )
```

Now having this try to get your most visited models for some period using this queryset:

```
period = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)
top_models = MyModel.objects.filter(
        hitcounts__hit__created__gte=period
    ).annotate(
        counts=models.Count('hitcounts__hit')
    ).order_by('-counts')
```